# Where with two AND

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm Trying to delete rows from database that don't have phone, chellphone, and email (all 3 together)

```
DELETE * 
FROM TEST
WHERE (((TEST.EMAIL1) IS Null)
AND ((TEST.PHONE3) IS Null)
AND ((TEST.PHONE1) IS Null));
```

For some reason if I'm doing only any two (email1, phone1 or phone3) it works, but when I'm adding second 'AND' it stop working. Any advise please.

Comment: If you mean there are no rows deleted by "stop working" - maybe there is no data where all 3 are NULL. Try firing a select with the same where condition.

Comment: Sorry by stop working I mean nothing was deleted

Comment: 6ton meant: maybe your third field is NOT null.

Answer (score 1):

With all `AND`s the parenthesis is not really necessary

```
DELETE
FROM TEST
WHERE TEST.EMAIL1 IS Null
AND TEST.PHONE3 IS Null
AND TEST.PHONE1 IS Null;
```

however, ensure that the values you expect to get deleted actually contain `NULL` and not something like empty string or the literal value of null.

You can check what information will be deleted by changing your statement to a select statement instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST
WHERE TEST.EMAIL1 IS Null
AND TEST.PHONE3 IS Null
AND TEST.PHONE1 IS Null;
```

Based on your own answer to your question you were running into empty strings, not nulls.  Another way to write what you wrote and to avoid ORs would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST
WHERE isnull(TEST.EMAIL1, '') <> ''
AND isnull(TEST.PHONE3, '') <> ''
AND isnull(TEST.PHONE1, '') <> '';
```

In the above we're stating that any null test.email1s we encounter, treat as an empty string then check that that values is not an empty string.

So basically - if any of those three fields are null OR empty string.  Same as your answer, just another way to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the WHERE clause looks okay in this example, but the '*' should be left out:

```
DELETE FROM TEST
    WHERE (((TEST.EMAIL1) IS Null)
        AND ((TEST.PHONE3) IS Null)
        AND ((TEST.PHONE1) IS Null));
```

If you have trouble after you delete the asterisk, re-copy-paste it back in, and we can see if there's a problem with parentheses or something. But the above bracketing looks okay (even if not necessary).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is going on with your case but I've cleaned up your statement a bit, as you shouldn't need all those `()` as far as I know and DELETE doesn't require the `*` as it should delete anything that matches your criteria. Try it out and let me know!

```
DELETE
FROM TEST
WHERE EMAIL1 IS Null
AND PHONE3 IS Null
AND PHONE1 IS Null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE *
FROM test
WHERE (((test.EMAIL1) ="") OR ((test.EMAIL1) IS NULL))
AND (((test.PHONE1) = "") OR ((test.phone1) IS NULL))
AND (((test.PHONE3) ="") OR ((test.phone3) IS NULL));
```

Worked for me. Thanks to all..

Comment: Please see my updated answer for another way to write this, again not having to deal with all the `()` and `OR`s

Answer (score 0):

You likely have no rows where all three are null. Check your data.

Comment: I have 2 rows where all 3 are empty

Comment: @Amiaki note that empty is not the same thing as `null`